# call php function on button click with ajax and parse through parameters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I would like to parse through parameters with ajax... is that at all possible? If so, how could I go about that?

HTML/JS

```
<script>
    function myAjax() {
       $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: '/ajax.php',
          data:{action:'follow'},
          success: function() {
             console.log("called");
          }
      });
    }
</script>
<button type='button' name='follow' id='follow' onclick='myAjax()'>Follow @<?php echo $profile ?></button>
```

ajax.php:

```
session_start();
require_once 'init.php';
if($_POST['action'] == 'follow') {
    User::follow($conn, $_SESSION["name"], $profile); 
// $conn is a db connection, $profile is the param I would like to parse through
} else {
    echo 'no req';
}
```

Comment: is there any error you are getting on the code you put ahead !!

Comment: So, your code isn't working? Are you getting any erros, PHP warning/erros or at browser console?

Comment: no errors in the code, I would like to know how to send a variable to ajax.php to use as a parameter

Comment: @Natelangner whatever you put in `data` object will get through to the php script.

Comment: @Natelangner I don't know what is your question exactly but you can see that $_POST['action'] on your `ajax.php` file right now. if you mean you can not see the `ajax.php` result on your console just change success.. to the `success: function(result){ console.log(result); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function myAjax(obj) { 
$.ajax({ 
   type: "POST",
    url: '/ajax.php', 
   data:obj,
    success: function() { console.log("called"); } 
   }); 
   }
```

Use like this:

```
  myAjax({action:" follow",id:1234});
```